# Selecting output audio device in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, hdmi

I am working on a project. And I'm struggling with this audio issue.
I have one PC and multiple monitors connected to the PC with HDMI. The PC has to run multiple Unity games at the same time which are the same program, but multiple processes. And the different processes are showing in the different monitors. But all the audio devices(the HDMI monitors) play all the sounds from the multiple processes because they run on the same PC. 
Is there a way to select a certain audio device to play audio in Unity?

Any help will be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there isn't an easy way. I am not sure if it will keep an already open device when you switch default audio device, but Unity will pretty much always just try to open a default device, so MAYBE you could change the default before running each application, but I have a feeling this will not be a good solution.

Comment: Thank you for answering:) Could you give me the way to change the default device? I have no idea how I could change something to do with audio.

Comment: if you click on the speaker icon (assuming you are using windows 10?) you get a slider and a dropdown with devices. This is your system default device and while not all apps change this dynamically, it will be a default device for new apps